# Razor Engine - SEO Meta tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, seo, razor, meta-tags

I need to place unique description and keywords meta tags to each page. Tried this. But its not clicking.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
    ViewBag.Description = "Test";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "Test1, Test2, Test3";
}
```

How do I place the meta tags in MVC 3 Razor Engine?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In the layout you could define a section:

```
<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("metas")
</head>
```

and in view:

```
@section metas
{
    <meta name="description" content="Test" />
    <meta name="title" content="Title" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Test1, Test2, Test3" />
    ...
}
```

or in the layout:

```
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.Description" />
    <meta name="title" content="@ViewBag.Title" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.Keywords" />
    ...
</head>
```

and in the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
    ViewBag.Description = "Test";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "Test1, Test2, Test3";
}
```

Comment: I want to upvote this at least three times. Simple, clean, right to the point.

Comment: thank you so much, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30151780/2218697) i used `ViewBag` because it handles null and just used `@ViewBag.Title` in layout and works great, but`@RenderSection` throws runtime undefined error if Title is null

Answer (score 26):

You can do as you did, but you have to link them in your _Layout.cshtml. Add this to your _Layout.cshtml in the `<head>` section:

```
@if(ViewBag.Description!=null)
{
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.Description" />
}
@if(ViewBag.Keywords!=null)
{
    <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.Keywords" />
}
```

Comment: what is the reason of using `@if(ViewBag.Description!=null)` ?

Comment: So it does not add the tag if it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit `<meta>` tags in your layout page that use the values.
You can get the values in the tags by writing `@ViewBag.Description`.