# how to create an else if statement in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to display some rows in a table. Depending on the UserGroup, the View should show different markup. An administrator can delete rows, but a moderator can only mark them as visible or invisible.

How do i write a proper if else statement in Razor?

The page is displayed correctly, but the page title is **Parse Error**

This is my code:

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.ViewModels.New.Question.MatrixRows

@{
    bool visible = Model.Visible;
}

<tr>
    <td>
    @if(visible) 
        {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(cn => Model.Row_Number, new { @class = "row required digits", size = 1 })
        }
    @if (!visible)
        {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(cn => Model.Row_Number, new { @class = "row required digits", size = 1, disabled = "disabled" })
        }
    </td>
    <td>
    @if(visible) 
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(bs => Model.Row_Description, new { @class = "rowdesc", size = 45 })
        }
    @if (!visible)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(bs => Model.Row_Description, new { @class = "rowdesc", size = 45, disabled = "disabled" })
    }
    </td>
    <td>
        @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Delete, new { @class = "mark-for-delete" })
            @Html.LinkToRemoveNestedForm("Slet", "tr", "input.mark-for-delete")    
        }
        @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Moderator"))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Visible, new { @class = "mark-for-visible" })
            @Html.LinkToDisableNestedForm("Deaktiver", "tr", "input.mark-for-visible")    
        }
        @Html.HiddenFor(id => Model.Row_Id)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Since you say the page is displayed correctly, is the question about the logic within the view or the **title** of the page?

Comment: The logic must be wrong, since it gives an error title?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The title has parse error because you did not set a title:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

now for an else statement, don't use back the `@` syntax:

```
@if(visible) 
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(bs => Model.Row_Description, new { @class = "rowdesc", size = 45 })
}
else
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(bs => Model.Row_Description, new { @class = "rowdesc", size = 45, disabled = "disabled" })
}
```

You are checking for a boolean, you just need an else. Also for `else if`, it works the same.

Your code could be simplified even more by just doing:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(bs => Model.Row_Description, new { @class = "rowdesc", size = 45, disabled = visible ? "" : "disabled" })
```

Because you are displaying the same code anyways, just changing the attribute based on a value. To me, this becomes more readable.

Answer (score 16):

As the question is for `else if` in `Razor` page, For example, I used below for some SEO purpose.

**In view**

```
@{

if (ViewBag.Option == "Mobiles")
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mobiles";
    ViewBag.Description = "Mobiles";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "Mobiles";
    
}
else if (ViewBag.Option == "holiday")
{
    ViewBag.Title = "holiday";
    ViewBag.Description = "holiday.";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "holiday";
}
else if (ViewBag.Option == "Laptops")
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Laptops";
    ViewBag.Description = "Laptops.";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "Laptops";
}
else
{
    ViewBag.Title = "home";
    ViewBag.Description = "home";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "home";
}

}
```

Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

You just use `else` **without** prepending an `@`.  However, I don't think that is the problem with your page title.  Perhaps you need to set the `ViewBag.Title` property? Your layout page may be depending on it being set.

```
@if(visible) 
    {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(cn => Model.Row_Number, new { @class = "row required digits", size = 1 })
    }
else
    {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(cn => Model.Row_Number, new { @class = "row required digits", size = 1, disabled = "disabled" })
    }
```

Title issue:

```
@{
    bool visible = Model.Visible;
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title;
}
```

Comment: Okay i corrected it, but i am still getting the Parse Error title. Howcome?

Comment: You corrected the `ViewBag.Title`?  I may have added that after you saw my original answer.