# Prepare If elseif else formula from UI in mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have to prepare formula from UI.

The formula is like IF ELSE IF condition.

Like :

```
IF (MiddleName != "")
    THEN FirstName + MiddleName
ELSE IF (LastName != "")
    THEN FirstName + LastName
ELSE
    THEN FirstName
```

There might be more ELSE IF condition as per requirement.
how can i implement in easier way ?
I have prepared on test app, in that i made using FORMCOLLECTION, finding key and then prepare formula condition.
but, there is too complex and lengthy process, if there is minor change in some condition, in future, there might be lots of work, like checking 2 conditions in if or else if.

Any help would be great appreciate.

EDITED :
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197680/how-to-create-an-else-if-statement-in-razor

Comment: Please , take a look on image. I was meant like that. I have to prepare the condition from UI.

Comment: I need to store that formula in database for further use.

Comment: This seems a bit kludgy. If you're worried about the formula changing and becoming a maintenance disaster, then you might wanna look into a larger solution like workflow foundation. But I felt like reinventing the wheel, I would probably attempt to solve this with some combination of predicate builder and strategy pattern. I would register each strategy in a dictionary with an enum key, then store the int values of the enum in the database. Then recall them from the db and fire up the right one for the case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
fieldsToBeChecked = //List of fields you want to check or enter values and remove Text from o.Text
var result = string.Join(" ", fieldsToBeChecked.Select(o => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(o.Text)));
```

Comment: @NareshParmar how come?