# If else Condition not support in MVC View in Microsoft visual studio 2013.How to use if statement in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC. In my case in View it gives error on else condition.Please guide me how to use it.. my View code is here

```
@model InputCustomer.Models.Customer

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DisplayCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        The Customer ID is @Model.Id<br/>
        The Customer Code is @Model.CustomerCode<br />
        @if (Model.Amount > 100){
        <%This is Privildged Customer%>  
        }
        @else{
         <%   This is a normal Customer%>
        }
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Stephen Mucke erorr is here     Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
<div>
 @if (Model.Amount > 100)
    {
    <text>This is Privildged Customer</text>  
    }
    else{
     <text>This is a normal Customer</text>
    }
</div>
```

Do not add addition **@** on else statement. Only one **@** per if and else statement or put them inside:

```
@{ 
  //TODO: Logic here
 }
```

Lastly don't edit our post, just put a comment if you have inputs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [how to create an else if statement in Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197680/how-to-create-an-else-if-statement-in-razor) you don't need to use `@` before `else`:

```
@if (Model.Amount > 100) {
    @:This is Privilged Customer
}
else {
    @:This is a normal Customer
}
```

Also `<%` and `%>` has no special meaning in Razor syntax. If you want text - simply keep it as text.

Comment: @AbdulmateenCh., I have updated my answer to include transition from C# to HTML in `if` block by using `@:` literal. Please let me know if you still have this issue or whether it is solved.