# Can we create meta tags in a view that has a master layout in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, meta-tags

In one of my views, I need to create some meta tags for social plugins, but couldn't find a way to do so.

Since the meta tags corresponds to this one view only, coding them in master-layout and then setting the values in View doesn't seem right.

Is there any way that I can create the meta tags in a View which can then be added to the head section of mater-layout. Or should i just add them to the master-layout and then set there values, like I do for description and keywords.

Comment: Some helpful answers can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531271/razor-engine-seo-meta-tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with [razor sections](https://www.google.com/search?q=razor%20sections). We do this for view-specific scripts and css, but you can apply the pattern for meta tags too.

In layout:

```
<head>
    <meta (global meta tag) ../>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("HeadMeta"))
    {
        @RenderSection("HeadMeta")
    }
</head>
```

In partial view:

```
@section HeadMeta
{
    <meta (view-specific social meta tag) ../>
}
```

Comment: You could shorten your first code sample to just `@RenderSection("HeadMeta", required: false)`.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is to use the same approach you use for description and keywords. And coding then in master-layout and then setting the values in View is OK, because their place is actually in the layout, and their value depends on the view that is shown.

Comment: actually they won't be used on any other views so I thought there might be some way to create meta tag in views for which they are meant :-P ... anyways thanks....will resort to that now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ViewBag`

In your master layout:

```
<meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription" />
```

In your partial:

```
@{
ViewBag.MetaDescription = "My meta description string";
}
```

Downside is that you have to create this ViewBag value in every partial (or do an `if(ViewBag.Metadescription != null)` check)