# asp.net MVC3 auto generate meta keywords and description based on page content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, seo, razor

I'm working on an MVC3 web application using the razor view engine. I'm looking for a solution to generate meta keywords and description automatically on my pages.

I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263568/asp-net-mvc-strategy-for-including-seo-information-such-as-meta-keywords-and-de) solution here on stackoverflow, the idea is looking good. But since I'm planning to post blogs etc... on my website I want the meta keywords and description to be auto generated based on the content of the page.

Soo far I've got the following things in mind. Let's say that the current HTML looks like below;

```
   <html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
            <header></header>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="sideBar"></div>
                <div id="pageHeader"></div>
                <div id="content">
                    <!--This part contains the dynamic content-->
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <footer></footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The desired situation for me would be something like below;

```
   <html>
    <head>
        @Html.MetaKeywords()
        @Html.MetaDescription()
    </head>
        <body>
            <header></header>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="sideBar"></div>
                <div id="pageHeader"></div>
                <div id="content">
                    <!--This part contains the dynamic content-->
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <footer></footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Said all this I've got the following questions left unanswered, hope someone can help.

1. The situation described above, with the HTML-helpers. Is this an good and logic approach to generate keywords and description on every single page, based on the content?
2. If this is, does anyone has experience and maybe an good example?
3. If not, are there any other good options? Other then using an attribute on each controller action? This still is an option, but it doesn't generate keywords an description based on my page content.

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to be able to auto generate the metadata based on the *text* inside the content div?

I would try passing that text / html / model into the MetaKeywords and MetaDescription functions, and allowing them to parse / analyze / look-up the information you need to put in the metadata.

```
   <html>
    <head>
        @Html.MetaKeywords(Model.ContentText)
        @Html.MetaDescription(Model.ContentText)
    </head>
        <body>
            <header></header>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="sideBar"></div>
                <div id="pageHeader"></div>
                <div id="content">
                    <!--This part contains the dynamic content-->
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <footer></footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, straight forward and pretty simple solution which I definately will keep in mind. Will try the solution STO mentioned first, I think this will make the view less heavier and faster to load because the application handles the creation of the meta data before the data is returned to the view

Comment: It'll definitely make the *view* creation faster, but more than likely that time will be spent in the action instead. You could either cache the entire view, or instead of using an Html.MetaKeyworks(...) method, you could call Html.Action with your metadata, cache it, and vary by param. This way your page will not be cached, but your meta data will (which is likely less important than, say, a comment or forum post).

Answer (score 1):

You should understand producing page content is the last stage of action processing, it performes directly to HttpContextBase.Response and generally server may never have whole content buffered, it may be sent to client due producing.

You may register your filter globally as described here http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx so you don't need to put attribute on each action method.

Comment: Good one with the action filters! Will try this out and let you know.

Comment: In the end I've chosen to use xixonia's solution. It was more convenient for me since I always will have some static html pages on my website where I want to determine my own keywords an description. This solution was more then sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

On the _layout.cshtml you can add a @Rendersection("header", false) In the header section!! False for the time being.
Later you have to change this to true or remove the required attribute.

On each page you can use now

```
@section header{
<meta name="Author" content="1SeoAdvies.nl" />;

Here you add every desired meta tag.

}
```

beware you don't have meta tags in the header section on the _layout page.